# How can i write this euqation in matlab ∆φ12 = [φ1 −φ2] (mod 2π)

Tags: matlab, math, physics, wave

I know the values for φ1 and φ1 and have to find the ∆φ12.
Background of the equation:
We know that the relationship between the absolute phase is Φ and the wrapped phase φ = Φ (mod 2π) with 2π discontinuities. Here the modulus operator is to convert the phase to a range of [0, 2π). Taking the modulus operation on Eq.(7) will lead to ∆φ12 = [Φ1 −Φ2] (mod 2π) = [φ1 −φ2] (mod 2π).
Thanks

Comment: "Modulus" means measure, and is another name for the magnitude, or absolute value, of a number. "Modulo" is the term you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick Google search for "matlab mod" would have given you the page for the [`mod`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mod.html) function. Anyway, here's what you need:

`dphi12 = mod(phi1 - phi2, 2*pi);`